# Checkbox state only available at next request

Tags: angular

I have this template:

```
<h2>Sailing profiles</h2>
<label *ngFor="let sailingProfile of sailingProfiles">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{sailingProfile.title}}" [(ngModel)]='sailingProfile.checkBoxState' (change)="sendParams()">
    {{sailingProfile.title}}<br>
</label>
<h2>Counters</h2>
<label *ngFor=" let counter of counters">
    {{counter.type}}: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='counter.value' (blur)="sendParams()"><br>
</label>
```

And in my code the checkbox state is only available at the next request. So I'll start with no checkboxes checked. Then I check one checkbox and in the sendParams() method no sailing_profile is added to the params array. Then I check another checkbox and then the sailing_profile of the first checkbox is added, not the sailing_profile I just selected. Am I using the wrong eventhandler and is the checkbox state set after the eventhandler?

```
sendParams() {
    let params = {};
    params["counters"] = [];
    params["sailing_profiles"] = [];

    this.counters.filter(
        c => "value" in c
    ).forEach(
        c => {
            params["counters"].push({
                "type": c["type"],
                "value": c["value"]
            })
        }
    );

    this.sailingProfiles.filter(
        s => "checkBoxState" in s && s["checkBoxState"]
    ).forEach(
        s => {
            params["sailing_profiles"].push({
                "title": s["title"]
            })
        }
    );

    this.paramsUpdated.emit(params);
}
```

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.4"

Comment: I've also tried (click)="sendParams()" but with the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(change)` and `(click)` events are processed before the `(ngModelChange)` event.

Use instead

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{sailingProfile.title}}" 
    [(ngModel)]='sailingProfile.checkBoxState' 
    (ngModelChange)="sendParams()">
```